# Creating a complex filter for a dataset in R

Tags: r, filter

I have a sample dataset which is as follows:

```
father<- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
mother<- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0) 
children <- c(0, 0, 2, 5, 2) 
cousins   <- c(0, 5, 1, 1, 4) 


dataset <- data.frame(father, mother, children, cousins)  
dataset


father  mother  children cousins
1      1       0      0
1      1       0       5
1      1        2       1
0     0        5       1
0     0        2       4
```

I would like to apply a condition-based filter so I can get all fathers marked with a '1' and mothers would be 0 OR children would be 0 OR cousins would be 0. In addition, I would also like this filter to select for all fathers with a 0 AND mothers with a 0 AND children with a 0 AND cousins with a 0. Any ideas on how I can go about creating such a filter for my dataset.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you just want two `filter`?

Comment: In your sample dataset, there are no rows in which `father` is `1` and `mother` is `0`.  Similarly, there are now rows with `father` = `0` and `children` = 0.  So do you want a data frame with zero rows as your output? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for:

```r
library(dplyr)
father<- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
mother<- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0) 
children <- c(0, 0, 2, 5, 2) 
cousins   <- c(0, 5, 1, 1, 4) 


dataset <- data.frame(father, mother, children, cousins) 

dataset %>% 
  filter(father == 1 & (mother == 0 | children == 0 | cousins == 0))
#>   father mother children cousins
#> 1      1      1        0       0
#> 2      1      1        0       5

dataset %>% 
  filter(father == 0 & mother == 0 & children == 0 & cousins == 0)
#> [1] father   mother   children cousins 
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A variation on @Dave's answer using `if_any` and `if_all`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

father<- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
mother<- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0) 
children <- c(0, 0, 2, 5, 2) 
cousins   <- c(0, 5, 1, 1, 4) 


dataset <- data.frame(father, mother, children, cousins) 

dataset |> 
  filter(father == 1, if_any(-father, ~ . == 0))
#>   father mother children cousins
#> 1      1      1        0       0
#> 2      1      1        0       5

dataset |> 
  filter(if_all(, ~ . == 0))
#> [1] father   mother   children cousins 
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Looks like these are being run in tidyverse. However, I am receiving the following error while running this package:

── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::ident()  masks dbplyr::ident()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
✖ dplyr::sql()    masks dbplyr::sql()

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this error in order to run the scripts you have shared above?

Comment: It's informational (when the tidyverse loads) rather than an error, i.e. telling you `dplyr::filter` will now be used instead of the base `stats::filter`. Presume the code is running okay?

Comment: Note, also, you can use the `%>%` pipe instead of `|>` if you're not on a recent release of R. `|>` is the relatively new native pipe.